# What is the order of event dispatch in Flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, events, event-handling

I have a checkbox that is bound to a property:

```
<mx:CheckBox label="Show All" selected="{showAll}"/>
```

I want to trigger an event when the checkbox is toggled that will read the value of `showAll` after a change:

```
<mx:CheckBox label="Show All" selected="{showAll}" click="_list.refresh()" />
```

Where, in this case, `_list` is an ArrayCollection object whose filter function depends on the `showAll` field to choose values.

It turns out that this doesn't work, or at least gives a strong appearance of not working (what with the values in the list not changing and all).  Is there a documented order of events for this, so that I can discover which events are dispatched in which order, and whether the binding value change will have fired the time the click event is dispatched?  Alternately, can someone recommend a better way of doing this?

Comment: Can you post more code?  I think you're probably very close, but the issue may be in a small detail or details of the approach.  Also, I think you may want to use the change event, rather than the click event (though, I couldn't really say without seeing your whole system).

Comment: I suspect you're right; the change event sounds like the right approach.  Let me try that...

Comment: Hm.  Nope.  The change event doesn't seem to do the trick.  I've set a breakpoint in the filter function, and after toggling the checkbox I see that the showAll property does not yet reflect the state of the checkbox.

Comment: I ended up using a change event that set the flag directly; apparently bindings are unidirectional, which I did not know.

Comment: Ah.  Yep.  Bidirectional in Flex4.  But, you can create ChangeWatcher objects in AS to handle binding by hand.  Check out the mx.binding.utils package.

Comment: You should post that as an answer; it'd get upvotes then.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have your data binding backwards...... changing the state of the check box by click or change event does not update the showAll variable.  It works the other way around... If you change the showAll Boolean it will automatically update the state of the check box to selected or unselected.

Answer (score -1):

In a generic sence, the flex event order is:

1. PREINITIALIZE
2. INITIALIZE
3. CREATIONCOMPLETE
4. UPDATE COMPLETE

Refer to http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layoutperformance_03.html